# Can a commercial airline pilot, flying either A320 or B737, charge people for a flight in their own personal Cessna 172?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots

Or would they have to be some registered business for the industry?

Comment: Please specify a country, as laws are different from place to place.

Comment: I think this is too broad. For example if he were to pay his own seat, and the charges only covered the cost of the aircraft, fuel, and oil, and he was not "holding out", it may be legal. The faa has a very broad definition of compensation which may not involve the exchange of money. Generally though the consensus in the faa world is no. Add a country and I can give an answer.

Comment: Presumably you mean either part 121 air carrier or part 135 charter operations, both of which have a lot of requirements beyond just holding an ATP (or in small piston 135 cases commercial) pilot certificate.  Otherwise this would only work as limited cost sharing under part 91.  Those requirements would be much more about *substance* than business structure; there might be some rules there but likely anyone doing this would have some sort of corporation as there are many non-flight reasons that would make sense anyway.